# Why is my Python program not recognizing the 'requests' library even after successful installation using pip?

Tags: python, pip

I try to write a simple code (bot) using API and I have some problems with library installing. For example: I need to install `requests`. I use `pip install requests` and I got `Successfully installed requests-2.31.0` but after I have this problem - `Library stubs not installed for "requests"`. How is this possible?
P.S. - And now I understand that I had some problems with my other code because the library did not work properly (or the program did not see it).

And problem Number 2 - I have a notice `A new release of pip is available: 23.0.1 -> 23.1.2`, I updated pip and got this message `Successfully installed pip-23.1.2` but after I still has this notice `A new release of pip is available: 23.0.1 -> 23.1.2`.
Is it possible that the problems are related?
I use VSCode.

I tried to uninstall and install again library but situation remained the same.

Comment: You're probably dealing with multiple versions of `pip`. Try installing packages with `python -m pip install ...` instead of `pip install` and see if that helps.

Comment: Isn't `requests` part of the standard library?

Comment: `A new release of pip is available: 23.0.1 -> 23.1.2` is just a notice and is probably irrelevant.

Comment: @TheTridentGuy No, it isn’t

Comment: @MarkTolonen You're right, I was thinking of `urllib.request`.

Comment: @CarlosGDCJ unfortunately nothing changed. I used "python -m pip install requests" but my code still got this problem " File "d:... line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'"

Comment: @rodys Ok. Then you are probably installing packages to one version of python and running your code with another. You said you're using VS Code. In VS Code, press Ctrl+Shift+`. A terminal should appear. Then run "python -m pip install requests" and try to run your code from that terminal using "python".

Comment: @CarlosGDCJ YES, You are right! I don't know how but I had two versions of Python.

Comment: Glad you were able to solve it. That problem is really annoying. The way most people deal with that is by using virtual environments. I'll post an answer and talk a bit about them

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the library you want to install is [types-requests](https://pypi.org/project/types-requests/). You can do that by:

```
pip install types-requests
```

As for your second problem, it is just a warning message and not an error. If you don't want to ignore it, first check what version of pip you are running by:

```
pip --version
```

then check the path of `pip` you are currently running:

```
which pip
```

then update that `pip`:

```
$(which pip) install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Hi @avi.ks, unfortunately your advice didn't help. I tried "pip install types-requests" but still got 
"line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'"

Answer (score 0):

What's probably happening is that you're **installing your packages to one version of python and using another one (without the packages) to run your code**.

In Python, packages are normally installed in a folder called `site-packages`, but every version of python has its own `site-packages` folder, as sharing would most likely cause compatibility problems.

If you plan on working with python for a while, having multiple versions is pretty much a given. You may want to keep old projects around while still keeping up to date with newer releases.

A popular way to avoid what you just experienced is by using **virtual environments**.

The general idea is to have a python installation that has everything your project needs and that can be turned on and off at will:

1. You turn it on before you start working on your project.
2. You work on your project. While it's on, it will make sure the virtual environment's installation of python is the one being used.
3. You turn it off when you're done.
4. When you're ready to continue, go back to step 1

To create virtual environments you can use something like [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) or [`conda`](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/).